# How to load an RData file with hebrew fields to tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am trying to load an RData file containing hebrew fields to tableau.

The following code adds a field containing hebrew letters to iris and saves
the dataframe to an RData file.

when tring to load the file to tableau - the following error message appears:

"Unable to complete action
Error reading file iris heb.RData: error code=-2
The number of encoding errors exceeded the user-defined limit, execution will be stopped"

What is the best possible way solve this?

```
iris_heb <- data.frame(iris, Heb_word = c("יום ראשון",
                               "יום שני",
                               "יום שלישי",
                               "יום רביעי",
                               "יום חמישי"))


head(iris_heb)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species                                                          Heb_word
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa <U+05D9><U+05D5><U+05DD> <U+05E8><U+05D0><U+05E9><U+05D5><U+05DF>
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa                 <U+05D9><U+05D5><U+05DD> <U+05E9><U+05E0><U+05D9>
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa <U+05D9><U+05D5><U+05DD> <U+05E9><U+05DC><U+05D9><U+05E9><U+05D9>
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa <U+05D9><U+05D5><U+05DD> <U+05E8><U+05D1><U+05D9><U+05E2><U+05D9>
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa <U+05D9><U+05D5><U+05DD> <U+05D7><U+05DE><U+05D9><U+05E9><U+05D9>
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa <U+05D9><U+05D5><U+05DD> <U+05E8><U+05D0><U+05E9><U+05D5><U+05DF>

save(iris_heb, file = "iris heb.RData")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you use?

If you use Windows you could try to save the data as a csv with UTF-8 encoding:

```
write_utf8_for_hebrew <- function(df, file) {
  line <- paste('"', names(df), '"', sep = "", collapse = " , ")
  data <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {paste('"', x, '"', sep = "", collapse = " , ")})
  writeLines(c(line, data), file , useBytes = TRUE)
}

write_utf8_for_hebrew(iris_heb, "iris_heb.csv")
```

Then you can load the data via >Connect >Text file

---

You could also try to change the encoding:

```
iris_heb$Heb_word <- as.character(iris_heb$Heb_word)
Encoding(iris_heb$Heb_word) <- "UTF-8"

save(iris_heb, file = "iris heb.RData")
```

---

### Update

- Statistical Files need a TDC 
  https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/examples_statfile.htm#Changeencoding
- Tableau does not support UTF-8
  https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/statfile_char_encoding.htm

I would therefore use ISO 8859-8

```
# set hebrew words to character type
iris_heb$Heb_word <- as.character(iris_heb$Heb_word)
# change the Encoding to ISO 8859-8
Encoding(iris_heb$Heb_word) <- "ISO 8859-8"
# save as RData
save(iris_heb, file = "iris heb.RData")
```

And set up a specific TDC file:

```
<connection-customization class='stat-direct' enabled='true' version='10.0'>
<vendor name='stat-direct' />
<driver name='stat-direct' />
  <customizations>
    <customization name='source-charset' value='iso-8859-8' />
  </customizations>
</connection-customization>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I use Windows. I need to use RData format to save space and time because my original dataset is very large. Using your second solution yields the same error message.

Comment: What do you get when you type this after the second solution:
`test <- get(load("iris heb.RData"))`


`Encoding(test$Heb_word)`

Comment: also check out: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/encoding-errors-exceed-user-defined-limit-connecting-to-statistical-file

Comment: I get "UTF-8" on all the vector values

Comment: Can you import the iris data alone using RData format?

Comment: Hi. I ran the code and saved the new iris_heb and set the tdc file as instructed and the same error message appears. i have another RData file called iris_original.Rdata that contains iris without the hebrew column and that is imported to tableau without problem.

Comment: Then I would contact the tableau support, you could refer to this discussion here